# catching specific exceptions coming from another Task method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, task

I have these 2 methods, and I know for sure that DoSomethingAsync returns a FormatException. However it is always catched in the last catch “Exception”

Why does CallSomethingAsync never catch the FormatException?

```
       public Task DoSomethingAsync()
       {
            //Do something that throws a FormatException 

            return Task.FromResult(0);           
       }

   public virtual string CallSomethingAsync()
   {
        try
        {
            this.DoSomethingAsync().Wait();

            return “Ok”;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return “FormatException”;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return “GeneralException”;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Task may return one or more Exceptions it throws an AggregateException containing all of the exceptions that occurred during the Task's execution.

You need to enumerate the InnerExceptions collection to explicitly handle the different types of Exception.